# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251 while resetting password

Tags: php, laravel, passwords

[image]I am facing problem on my live server but there is nothing wrong in my local i just test from my local and push my changes to live and i am facing this issue i dont know where is the issue:

My Controller:

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
  use ResetsPasswords;
}
```

My Routes:

```
<?php

  \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::routes();

Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.request');

     Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

My View:

```
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $email or old('email') }}" required autofocus>
                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
            </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Reset Password
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I dont know what is issue in url or somewhere else as its working properly on my local.
Your help needs here i have also attached the screen shot of my error.

Comment: The methodNotAllowed exception indicates that a route doesn't exist for the HTTP method you are requesting.
If it's work on local, you should check .htaccess file on remote server or nginx config for rewrite rules.

Comment: are you sure the routes.php is updated on server?

Comment: yes its updated on server

Comment: `Auth::routes()` should handle all routes you need for authentication, login, registration and also password reset. Have you tried it without your "custom" routes?

Comment: Yes i have tried with custom routes as you can see i have also defined the routes other than Auth::routes()